# Resize CardView on bind RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want to resize the width of a CardView that within a RecyclerView, but when I use CardView.LayoutParams to change the width throws an exception, someone help me? below is the code:

### list_item_calendar_hours.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHour"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:text="13:00"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvHour"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvHour"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
    android:alpha="0.12"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView                  
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cv_app"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvHour"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/green"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="1dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### RVAdapterAppointmentHours.java

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    String hours = (String) mItemsData.get(position);
    viewHolder.tvHour.setText(hours);
    for (AppointmentModel model : mListAppointments) {
        int hour =    DateUtils.extractHour(DateUtils.stringToDate(model.getDate()));
        if (formatHour(hour).equals(hours)) {
            viewHolder.cvAppointment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.i("ARTHUR", String.valueOf(viewHolder.line.getWidth()));
            viewHolder.tvDesc.setText(model.getMinutes());
            break;
        } else {
            viewHolder.cvAppointment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.tvDesc.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

### Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams   cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
```

### Screen

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, error is self-explanatory:
  `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams`

The view you are performing operation on is of type `RelativeLayout` and you try to access it as `FrameLayout`

Comment: Ok, I know, but how do to change the width of dynamic form?

Comment: How about `.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));`? See if that works out